# Crash in VS2013 SP5 when inserting initializer_list into vector<string>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013, initializer-list

Seeing a crash with the below code. I know initialize_lists have a poor reputation in VS, but I thought most of them were fixed with 2013 sp3. The same code works fine in g++ (6.1). Am I missing something here? This seems far too simple.

The debugger suggests a problem with an invalid iterator in the xstring module. The same code works find with integers, so I'm guessing it relates to some sort of string specific optimization.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::string> x = {"a","b","c","d"};

    for(auto i : x)
        std::cout << i << ":";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    x.insert(x.end(), {"e","f"});  // Crash here

    for(auto i : x)
        std::cout << i << ":";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW - in VC2013 RC4 if I add a try/catch around the `insert`, it catches `bad_alloc`.  If I `insert` `{std::string("e"), "f")}` it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be surprised if you try inserting 3 elements like `x.insert(x.end(), {"e","f", "g"});`. No crash, right!

This is a bug in MSVC 2013 and seems to be fixed in MSVC 2015. Here is an explanation to shed some light to where the problem occurs. If you try only declaring `std::string a{ "a", "b" };` you will see that it compiles fine but it causes a crash. If you add one more element, then it won't compile at all. So, what happens with the insert is that it calls the `string` constructor instead of calling `vector` constructor.

Comment: You're right about 3 text values working, but for the two-value case I've added debug trace to all overloads of `insert` and don't see *any* overload being called.  It seems to throw while preparing the parameters, which is crazy - trace in the `initializer_list<>` constructor's not even displayed.

Comment: Thanks. At least that confirms it's a compiler bug, if a bit of a weird one. Upgrading isn't an option just yet, will just have to avoid it.

Seems I can work around by prefixing std::initializer_list<std::string>{"e","f"}.