# C++ Incorrect behavior of std::string initialization

Tags: c++, string, stl

Why does the following code compile? It compiles and runs fine with clang and prints `first.` But, I believe the correct behavior should be to complain and issue a proper error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s{ "first", "second" };
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

This question is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062172/crash-in-vs2013-sp5-when-inserting-initializer-list-into-vectorstring/37063463#37063463).

Comment: It is because the "first" string has an implicit "\0" at the end of it....that tells the `string` object to stop looking for more chars (even though it probably is still allocating the full memory of the "second" to)

Comment: @DarthRubik: No. That's not what's happening.

Comment: The underlying problem is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112281/c11-initializer-list-fails-but-only-on-lists-of-length-2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string` has a template constructor that takes two iterators. When you pass string literals, they will decay to `char const*`, which qualifies as an iterator. However, since those pointers do not form a valid range, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @EissaN. No. It's a bug in your code. Your program exhibits undefined behavior, and therefore clang is under no obligation to do anything in particular, and can, as far as the C++ standard is concerned, do anything at all.

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior.

This is invoking a constructor of `std::string` that accepts two iterators, the beginning and the ending iterator value. Because both initialization parameters have the same type, they are interpreted as a pair of iterators, and match this particular overloaded constructor.

The values of the character pointers are interpreted as beginning/ending iterator values. It just happens to work with clang, but with gcc this throws an exception.